# « Bon appétit ! » est-il poli ?

Tags: politesse, alimentation

Je souhaitais un « bon appétit » avant le repas, mais on m'a dit que ça n'était pas poli.

1. Est-ce vrai ?
2. Si c'est vrai, pourquoi ?

Comment: Franchement j'ai jamais entendu ça dans l'est. Par contre, j'ai vu des films ou « bon appétit » est définitivement dit d'une façon désinvolte ou avec l'idée que la personne va avoir un problème en mangeant (nourriture empoisonnée...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tout dépend. Dans la plupart des contextes, en France, c'est tout à fait admis, mais il existe effectivement des limites :

- Dans un contexte informel (famille, collègues que l'on connait bien, amis), c'est une habitude. On entend même parfois *bon ap'*, dans les cas les plus informels.
- Dans un contexte moyennement formel, cela peut se dire sans problèmes. Il est m'est arrivé de l'entendre de la part de personnes hiérarchiquement plus élevées que moi au travail, tout comme il m'est arrivé de le dire à ces personnes.
- Dans les contextes les plus formels cependant, cela peut passer pour une familiarité déplacée. C'est dans ces derniers cas qu'il convient d'être prudent. Certains recueils de *bonnes manières* bannissent cette expression et invitent même à répondre de façon détournée si l'on est destinataire de ces mots ([une simple recherche le montre](https://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&q=bon%20appetit#safe=off&hl=fr&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bon%20appetit%22%20%22bonnes%20mani%C3%A8res%22&oq=%22bon%20appetit%22%20%22bonnes%20mani%C3%A8res%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.7372.11555.0.11687.20.20.0.0.0.1.336.1812.16j3j0j1.20.0...0.0...1c.1.18.psy-ab.0NBuehkRdMc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.d2k&fp=34d5e83669cd334&biw=1680&bih=925)). J'ignore pourquoi.

Comment: Merci Shlubu pour toutes ces précisions. Ceci répond parfaitement à ma première question, mais la seconde reste ouverte.

Comment: Tiré du premier lien de la recherche Google que tu indiques : *On n'accentue pas le côté animal de l'homme, un repas est avant tout un art de la table en bonne compagnie, et non pas un instinct primaire. Dire "Bon appétit" revient à dire "bon estomac", "bon transit intestinal"*

Comment: Avec plaisir ! Et bon ap' :)

Comment: Merci Alexis, ceci répond à la deuxième question.

Comment: Oui Alexis, j'ai vu. Mais je n'ai Su déterminer si c'est l'interprétation qu'en fait l'auteur du recueil ou si c'est la raison historique.

Comment: "Bon ap'"... Excusez-moi... Enfin nous sommes entre nous, donc "Bon ap'"

Comment: @Shlublu c'est surtout du 2nd degré, voir l'entrée *Suicide* par exemple :)

Comment: Effectivement... fantastique :)

Comment: J'aurais eu tendance à plussoyer les deux premiers points, mais un lien google qui pointe vers rien du tout, en espérant montrer qu'un truc douteux est évident, ça détruit complètement la réponse.

Comment: Les serveurs des bons restaurants ont tendance à dire "Bonne continuation" et non pas "Bon appétit", ce qui tend à laisser penser que le bon appétit ne devrait pas être souhaité. Personnellement, j'ai toutefois tendance à trouver malpoli mes collègues s'ils commencent à manger sans souhaiter un bon repas ou un bon appétit autour d'eux.

Comment: On peut aussi penser que le « bonne continuation » dit en servant un plat, veut simplement éviter la redondance avec le « bon appétit » dit en servant l'entrée.

Comment: sic du deuxième lien de google: *« Historiquement : on n'accentue pas le côté animal de l'homme, un repas est avant tout un art de la table en bonne compagnie, et non pas un instinct primaire. Dire "Bon appétit" revient à dire "bon estomac", "bon transit intestinal". »* sans pour autant être une référence, me semble ne pas être une mauvaise explication du « pourquoi » ;-)

Comment: @LaurentG. Tu voulais certainement écrire *les serveurs des restaurants **chers***. Il y a de nombreux restaurants très recommandables où la courtoisie et l'humanité remplacent avantageusement la servilité rigide et malsaine des pince-fesses mondains. Loin des snobinards émasculés du verbe, on y souhaite un *bon appétit* à ceux qu'on aime. C'est-à-dire à tout le monde, à peu de choses près.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Pourquoi tant d'agressivité ? Souhaiter un bon appétit est considéré comme déplacé par la plupart sinon tous les manuels de savoir-vivre et de bonnes manières. On ne peut pas reprocher aux personnels de certains restaurants de remplacer cette formule par une autre qui est acceptable quels que soient les convives.

Comment: @Jiliagre Ce n'est pas de l'agressivité, plutôt une certaine indignation face à ce que je considère comme étant une dangereuse confusion. Pour le dire plus calmement et (espèrons-le) plus clairement, la question initiale ne spécifie aucun contexte culturel ou social, et il me semble important de préciser que pour **une grande majorité** de personnes et de situations, la formule **n'est pas** impolie. Et cependant, il existe en effet un contexte social spécifique (la haute bourgeoisie, et par effet de singerie, une partie de la petite bourgeoisie) dans lequel la formule est mal reçue. \[...\]

Comment: \[...\] Je suis d'accord avec le commentaire de Laurent d'une manière générale, je voulais juste dire : attention à ce qu'on appelle *les bons restaurants*. Un étranger, préparant un voyage en France et lisant cette page, serait induit en erreur en se disant « attention expression interdite, c'est familier/grossier ».

Comment: @RomainVALERI Je ne partage pas cette indignation qui me semble exagérée. Bien que je ne fasse pas partie de la haute bourgoisie ni ne la singe et que je dise « Bon ap' » à mes collègues qui vont déjeuner, je ne dirais jamais « Bon appétit » dans certaines occasions, disons celles où je ne mettrais pas non plus mes coudes sur la table. Cela-dit, je ne suis jamais choqué ou contrarié si on me le souhaite, et encore moins bien sûr s'il s'agit d'un étranger.

Comment: L'argumentaire en défaveur du _bon appétit_ pourrait tout aussi bien être utilisé pour jeter l'opprobe sur le fait même de manger en société. Les arts de la table se contenteraient alors de seulement goûter les plats et, à l'image des goûteurs de grands vins, de recracher la bouchée qui a excité les papilles dans un récipient prévu à cet effet.

Comment: @mouviciel Comment ? Gouter des plats *organiques* avec sa bouche *physique* ? Quelle horreur ! Enfin mon bon ami reprenez-vous, nous ne sommes quand même pas des êtres tangibles et mortels. On commence ainsi et l'on finit par chier de la merde par le cul, m'a-t-on-dit...

Answer (score 16):

J'avoue être assez surpris des réponses déjà présentes et confirmant, au moins en partie, la **prétendue impolitesse** de l'expression.

Pour qu'elle soit déplacée ou impolie, il faut réellement un contexte spécial voire exceptionnel, comme par exemple le fait de l'adresser sur un ton plein d'entrain à une personne qu'on sait en deuil, ou ayant un souci lié précisément à l'appétit (voulant maigrir, notamment).

A la lecture de ta question, celle qui m'est venue immédiatement était : « Mais *qui* t'a dit ça? »

Il m'est surtout en effet arrivé de voir quelque misanthrope s'offusquer de ce genre de détails d'étiquette pour rappeler et souligner un écart social. Le prétexte en vaut un autre. Question de point de vue, sans doute.

On peut également noter que dans presque tous les contextes où la formule est bienvenue (donc une grande majorité de cas pour une très grande partie de la population), **c'est l'absence de la formule** et le fait de commencer à manger directement qui constitue un manque de politesse et de convivialité.

Et donc, c'est vrai, l'expression est **vulgaire**, dans le sens de *commune, populaire, utilisée par tout le monde*. Comme le mot *bonjour*.

Comment: +1 pour "comme le mot *bonjour*."

Comment: Sur ce point, nos avis convergent. Ce qui m'interpellait, c'était que cette expression puisse être considérée comme impolie. Qui m'a dit ça? Ma mère, elle qui m'avait toujours dit le contraire... (Elle a entendu ça à la radio).

Comment: @Pierre C'est une nuance de sensibilité récupérée par les "bonnes manières" et non un mode sociétal : on se réfère à la personne la plus délicate, la plus sensible (je me réfère à la sensibilité artistique et non à la sensiblerie ou la susceptibilité) que l'on ne veut heurter. Mettre un tag sur la Joconde pour dire *c'est moi qui l'ai fait*, est aussi choquant que de lâcher un sonore *bon appétit* en présence de personnes dont on [veut] respecte[r] la sensibilité.

Comment: Oui, je comprends ton raisonnement, cl-r. Bien qu'étant en désaccord au moins partiel, je trouve ta réponse sensée et cohérente. Seulement, je trouve que ce *bon appétit* est un des avatars de cette détestation du corps qui est une caractéristique chrétienne au départ, mais que la modernité a (malheureusement) réinventée. Je ne suis pas sociologue, mais il me semble qu'il y a d'excellents travaux pour ceux que ça intéresse. [Patrick Baudry](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Baudry_%28sociologue%29), *Le corps extrême*, par exemple.

Answer (score 10):

Pour répondre au deuxième point, il s'agit d'un refus tautologique :

L'hôte (principalement la maîtresse de maison, mais celui qui invite s'il n'est pas marié) s'est donné beaucoup de mal à choisir le menu, à dresser la table et à y accorder les voisinages en fonction des affinités qui autorisent d'enfreindre le protocole pour réaliser un [plan de table](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_de_table) convivial, à retarder un peu le début du repas pour que tout le monde ait eu le temps de s'habiller, ou tout simplement de se dégager des embouteillages.

- Si l'hôte dit bon appétit, sous entendre : et il y a intérêt avec tout le mal que je me suis donné.
- Si c'est l'invité qui l'exprime, on pensera « on sait que tu as les crocs », mais ce n'est pas à toi de donner le signal de départ.

De toute façon il n'est pas très subtil de dire ce que l'on est en train de faire.

C'est pourquoi, enjoindre ses invités à passer à table et, pendant que la conversation continue, s'enquérir du regard de savoir si le service a été fait pour tout le monde, puis, après avoir délicatement pris une première cuillerée du consommé (ou de toute autre entrée), remercier discrètement le service (ou dire que ce qui est servi correspond à ce que l'on veut offrir, dans des situations plus simples) permet à tout le monde de savourer l'instant en silence et d'apprécier d'une mine réjouie les parfums de la première bouchée avant que la conversation s'anime à nouveau.

Imaginez-vous alors dire « bon appétit » ?  *mufle, goujat, butor, plouc, 
malappris, grossier, sauvage, impoli, pignouf, indélicat, rustre,…*  et il y en tant d'autres encore qui ne seront plus invités.

---

Pour complément :

Une autre raison pourrait venir de la concurrence avec le *[Bénédicité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9n%C3%A9dicit%C3%A9)*, petite prière de remerciement pour la nourriture préparée, dite cette fois par le chef de famille. Avec la perte d'influence de l’Église dans la vie quotidienne, elle ne se pratique plus en public.

Dire ensuite *bon appétit*, reviendrait à prendre la place de celui que l'on vient de remercier.

En revanche, dans un restaurant où chacun règle son addition, pour s'amuser des règles de politesse, on peut répondre « bon ? seulement ? et pourquoi pas gargantuesque ? »… et lancer des échanges sur les bonnes pratiques sociales.

Si l'on a envie de donner un signal pour que tous les convives commencent ensemble, lancer un « Et si on commençait ? » car il s'agit en fait de suspendre la convivialité de la conversation pour pratiquer l'activité pour laquelle on a les pieds sous la table.

Comment: Analyse intéressante et poussée, on comprends mieux le contexte.

Comment: La référence au bénédicité est très pertinente pour comprendre l'usage et surtout l'histoire de l'expression. Le reste m'échappe en grande partie. Je dois être un rustre, probablement... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

La bonne éducation se moque de la bonne éducation, pour paraphraser Pascal.

En effet, la situation ne saurait être symétrique: le rustre est dans son rôle lorsqu'il gène et qu'il dérange – et qui peut sérieusement lui en vouloir? – mais qu'une personne de bonne éducation se trouve offusquée et prête à considérer un hôte comme un “plouc” ou un “pignouf” parce qu'il ne respecte pas des usages de cet ordre, voilà qui est, à mon sens, véritablement choquant. Une bonne éducation qui se fissure aussi facilement n'a d'autres noms qu'entre-soi et philistinisme.

Comment: C'est aussi dans ce sens que je l'entends, nos réponses convergent. +1 pour la belle formule.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas cette citation de Pascal -que j'admire par ailleurs- citation qui je trouve, résume parfaitement la situation. Ce genre de problématique cependant, si elle me hérisse toujours ne me choque plus, aussi je la qualifierai également d'entre-soi, voir même de pédanterie, mais l'emploi du terme philistinisme ne me semble pas adapté.

Comment: Simple note à propos de Pascal ; je parodie plus que je ne paraphrase, puisque le passage auquel je fais référence dit : “La vraie éloquence se moque de l'éloquence, la vraie morale se moque de la morale ; […]
Se moquer de la philosophie, c'est vraiment philosopher”.

Comment: Ok KO, ceci explique cela, cette dernière citation est plus familière à mes oreilles, mais effectivement, le pastiche m'était apparu comme tout à fait crédible en temps que citation de Pascal, félicitations!

Answer (score 4):

« Bon appétit » est une formule d'origine populaire ou petite-bourgeoise qui, dans la majorité des cas, n'est plus, aujourd'hui, ressentie comme telle. Pour donner une idée de cette connotation populaire, on peut penser à cet extrait de *La fille du puisatier* de Pagnol, où le père (le puisatier) de la jeune fille tombée enceinte des œuvres du rejeton d'une famille bourgeoise salue celle-ci d'un sonore « Bon appétit, m'sieurs dames » (formule doublement vulgaire, mais le puisatier n'en a évidemment pas conscience) qui marque la distance sociale entre les deux parties.

Comment: Je plussoie pour la référence, qui à le mérite de mettre en relief la problématique de manière très simple.