# Expression idiomatique — bon appétit pour les boissons

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, alimentation, travail

Contexte: Je travaille dans un café et souvent lorsque je fais du café ou un latte, je dis en anglais "Enjoy!".

Lorsque le client parle français et la commande inclut de la nourriture, je dis : "Bon appétit".

**Peut-on dire "bon appétit" lorsqu'il y a seulement des boissons? Sinon, quelle expression peut-on utiliser?**

J'ai cherché la réponse sur Google et WordReference ainsi que je n'ai rien trouvé.

SVP inclure le contexte culturel dans votre réponse. Merci.

Comment: J'ai l'habitude de me faire servir des cafés ou boissons, et je dirais qu'en français je n'entends jamais d'équivalent de "Enjoy!".  Dans tous les cas, "bon appétit" est lié à la nourriture, au repas, pas à un café ou une boisson.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Entendre *bon appétit* après avoir commandé des boissons me semblerait particulièrement étrange. En fait, cela me donnerait l'impression que la personne ne maîtrise pas la langue.

*Bonne dégustation*, en ce genre de cas, me semble parfait.

Comment: +1, C'est vraiment une traduction élégante et plus complète du "Soyez heureux" (de ce que vous allez savourer)

Comment: Un simple *et voilà !* juste après avoir servi la dernière boisson me paraitrait quand même plus naturel, …à moins qu'il ne s'agisse de boissons très sophistiquées?

Comment: Je rejoins les avis de Shlublu et Stéphane, c'est d'ailleurs la réponse que je voulais formuler hier soir, sans en être 100% satisfait...mais à part *et voilà !* et *bonne dégustation*, je ne vois pas ce qui pourrait être dit d'autre.

Comment: Peut-être mon impression est modifiée par l'usage qu'on fait en italien du mot "dégustation", c'est-à-dire à propos de vins, mais je serais surprise si l'on me souhaitais "bonne dégustation" quand j'ai acheté un café ou un verre d'eau. Je croix que "et voilà" comme suggéré par @Stéphane Gimenez soit mieux et plus correcte.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'aime cette expression... c'est simple et neutre.

Comment: Je proteste avec véhémence que Shlublu ait eu bonne réponse puisque c'est moi qui ait parlé de bonne dégustation the first one ! Je vais monter en haut d'une grue comme tout le monde en attendant que justice me soit faite !

Comment: Pas de souci, qu'elle soit tienne :) Descends de cette grue maintenant, tu vas tomber :-)

Comment: @Istao Votre réponse était seulement "Bonne dégustation m'sieurs dames."  Shlublu a donné plus de contexte et une bonne explication.  J'ai posé la question en demandant le contexte.  Si votre réponse était plus complet, je l'aurais choisie.  D'accord?

Afin de "vous faire le justice", je peux donner un "up-vote", parce que votre réponse est utile.

Comment: Bapf. Bumpf. Grumpf.

Answer (score 5):

L'expression que j'aurais le plus tendance à utiliser en matière de boissons serait « À la [bonne] vôtre ! ».

Cependant, bien que courante, cette expression n'est pas applicable dans tous les contextes. Par exemple, si les interlocuteurs se sont juste servis un verre d'eau, de jus de fruit, ou d'une boisson « simple », ce sera très probablement hors sujet.

Cette expression sera plus couramment utilisée dans un contexte de consommation d'alcool, et plus généralement lorsqu'il y aura quelque chose à célébrer.

**EDIT :** J'en oubliais le contexte principal de la question qui mentionnait le bar et le café. Dans ce cas, l'expression « À la [bonne] vôtre ! » n'est pas appropriée : elle ne s'utilise pas - ou peu - pour le café, et comme l'évoque Gilles, elle sera presque exclusivement employée lorsque l'on envisage d'accompagner notre interlocuteur par une boisson semblable ou proche.

Comment: Surtout, « à la vôtre » ne se dit que par quelqu'un qui boit avec les autres.

Comment: @Gilles Oui, ça mérite d'être noté :)

Answer (score 5):

Comme les autres réponses le mentionnent, je trouverais aussi *bon appétit* étrange pour des boissons. Je dirai éventuellement *à votre santé!* ou simplement *santé!*.

Je trouve le *bonne dégustation* correct, mais cela ne s'applique à mon avis que dans le cas d'un verre de vin. À mon sens, on peut *déguster* un verre de vin mais pas un verre d'eau ou un soda.

Comment: "à votre santé!" ce n'est pas quand on boit soi-même ? "Je bois à votre santé"

Answer (score 4):

*Bonne dégustation m'sieurs dames.*

Answer (score 4):

J'éviterai toute dérivation du type "bon appétit /bonne dégustation" qui peuvent être considérées comme impolies par certains.

Je me contenterai de "Et voici"  (Here you go - more formal), pour indiquer aux clients la présence de leur commande.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vraiment compris pourquoi certains trouveraient encore cela impoli de nos jours … Sinon, en complément je dirais que "S'il vous plait" serait également approprié si non plus commun.

Comment: @JeromeJ Pourquoi impoli ? Voir [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/bon-appetit-est-il-poli) pour quelques éléments de réponse. A l'origine, c'est un héritage de l'ère chrétienne et de la détestation du corps. La modernité en a repris les conclusions mais avec d'autres fondements, pour tout ce que le corps implique de *mortel, limité, humain*. Dans notre société si adolescente et prométhéenne, ce rejet des limites de la nature est l'un des chainons de la rhétorique libérale classique.

Comment: @JeromeJ Cela dit, ce n'est impoli qu'à une certaine bourgeoisie, ainsi qu'à ceux qui l'imitent en voulant lui plaire.

Answer (score 0):

Avec plusieurs collègues nous nous sommes posé cette questiion.
Et à vrais dire je trouve que bonne dégustation est un peu trop. Et là d’un coup nous nous sommes dit que *bon rafraîchissement * semblais le plus propice.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu « bon rafraîchissement ».

Answer (score -3):

L'expression "*bon appétit !*" ne s'appliquerait pas seulement à la nourriture en général, pas seulement la nourriture "solide" type viande, poisson, fruit ou légume. Voici un lien qui traite du sujet : http://usagesetconvenances.wordpress.com/tag/bon-appetit/

NB : le même lien précise d'ailleurs qu'on ne devrait pas dire bon appétit.

Comment: Quelle est l'expression le mieux afin d'être poli?

Comment: @PatrickSebastien Voir cette question : ["Bon appétit" est-il poli?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6787/217)